# How to change characters in a certain position within a string... Python

Tags: python, string, variables, random

Very Basic Question:

If the string MYZR27EE7 was saved to the variable origin.
How would I be able to changed the character 2 to a different random number?

(I am very very very new to Python and programming in general, so an easy to follow explanation would be great.)

**THX**

Comment: Please post your code (so we can see what you have tried so far) and tell us where you got stuck. You should also visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you cannot change a string. You have to use slicing or convert to list and back to string. you want to change by value or by position? that's too broad as it is.

Comment: I apologise about it being a bit too open of a question. It was worded horribly as I didn't have a clue what to do. All worked out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the logic in the snippet below to swap any character you want with a random number.

```
from random import randint
origin = "MYZR27EE7"
origin = origin[:4] + str(randint(0,9)) + origin[5:]
print(origin)
```

Results:

```
# MYZR17EE7
# MYZR67EE7
```

Comment: Thank you so much, though before I checked back on here I worked it out myself. I believe your code is a lot more efficient though. So I will be using that :)

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below, to replace any char with a respective char at a given index, if you wish not to use the function `.replace()`

word

```
word = 'MYZR27EE7'
index = 4
char = str(random.randint(0,9))

word = word[:index] + char + word[index + 1:]
print word

o/p: MYZR57EE7
o/p: MYZR87EE7
```

And if you want to use `.replace()` use this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random
import string
string = "MYZR27EE7";
numb = str(random.randint(0,9));
print string.replace("2", numb)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help